# Export to CSV with customizing the font color using PHP

Tags: php, csv

In my application i am able to export data to CSV file successfully, But i need some contents of the CSV file to be in "bold" and "color".
So is it possible way to do it? If so please help me out.

Comment: CSV is a plain-text format, there's no way to apply bold or color to the contents and still have it be a standard CSV file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a valid option, you can export to Excel format using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). This supports font color, weight etc..

Answer (score 2):

The basic CSV file format doesn't have any way to represent such attributes. If the file is to be read by a specific application, maybe it supports a richer format that you can output in?

Comment: So you mean there is no way to do it?

Comment: @sandeep: Not if you want to keep it as an actual, honest-to-goodness, CSV file. If you just want something that'll open in Excel, Open Office, Google Docs, etc, see Burak's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can not do it with CSV.  But if your target program to read the CSV is Excel, you can create a XLS spreadsheet.

But I have had very good success using Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer:   http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.php

Give it a shot.

Comment: S_E_W is essentially dead in the water. It's better to use PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) instead, which supports the latest Excel formats and has a more complete API

Answer (score 0):

CSV file is just comma separated values file so it can't be formatted. this is a simple text file with `.csv` extension. If you want to format then exporting into excel.